# How to plot distribution with given mean and SD on a histogram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a following Pandas dataframe named Scores,following is the subset of it

```
      0
0  25.104179
1  60.908747
2  23.222238
3  51.553491
4  22.629690
5  53.338099
6  22.360882
7  26.515078
8  52.737316
9  40.235152
```

When I plot a histogram it looks like following

[image]

Now, I want to plot a distribution on this histogram with mean=37.72 and SD=2.72
I am able to generate a distribution with following code

```
x= np.linspace(10,90,1000)
y = norm.pdf(x, loc=37.72, scale=2.71)    # for example
pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
```

How can I embed this on histogram ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
plt.hist( The histogram data)
plt.plot( The distribution data )
plt.show()
```

The `plt.show` will show both figures embedded in a single figure.